# dynamic image in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

What is the standard way of serving and storing dynamic images in meteor

PS. I cannot use any package that uses public or subscribe. So any use of mongo apis like Collection.find() in the client, has to be served by calling some function to server.

Comment: You can try the CollectionFS and GridFS packages for storing images directly in your database or use something like Nginx for storing and serving files.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "dynamic images". From where I'm standing, here are some options.

The easy way: you store and serve them directly from your public directory. If you have an image in `/public/images/lolcat.png` you can load it using the url `/images/lolcat.png`. However, be warned about one thing: as long as you are in development more, the server will reload each time you add or modify one of your public assets.

The less easy way, you can use nginx to serve your content. See more info about it here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx

The tricky way, you fork a package like [file-collection](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-file-collection) and you replace the publications with server methods returning a cursor (I never did that but I assume it is possible).

You would then call your method like below, and use `result` as a cursor.

```
Meteor.call("meteorMethod", dataObject, function(error, result){ 
    if(error){ 
        console.log("error", error); 
    } 
    if(result){ 

    } 
});
```